# PostgreSQL+NHibernate -> named parameter in LIKE section

Tags: string, postgresql, nhibernate, sql-like, named-parameters

In Spring+Hibernate app im trying to use a named parameter pasend
query should sum values from xml document saved in database as text.

```
    SELECT  document_type, 
     SUM(CAST(substring(document_content ,'<ab.*>(.*[0-9])</ab>') as float)) as value, COUNT(*)
     FROM  statistic_data_test 
     WHERE column LIKE :param1::text
     GROUP BY document_type 
     ORDER BY value DESC
```

param1 is named parameter passed to program via URL.
Whole query and parameter names are dynamically created by user.

code shown above works fine, but i need an ability to find not only exact match, but i cant concatenate stings in query.
For now, in one part of code i'm checking if type is text, and if so, i add % marks as suffix and prefix.

What i wont, is move % marks from parameter to query string, but things like

```
WHERE column LIKE '%'+:param1::text+'%'
```

turns errors

How can it be done? How to concatenate stings in query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the strategy, keep the goal.

Use the `position` function.

```
position(:param1::text in column) <> o
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks what i was looking for ;)
But is there a way to check if nothing else except that param is in column? Cant be done by LIKE ofc, but would be good to use one method.

Comment: @T.G - Well, `LIKE` can do that simply by including no percent signs, but you would suffer a major performance hit on any larger data if you did not just use `=` for that job.  Hammer for the nails, screwdriver for the screws.